# TagLib# using "/" as separator in Performers tag?

Tags: vb.net, tags, separator, taglib-sharp

The code I'm using...

```
For Each file As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(directory)
    Dim fi As FileInfo = New FileInfo(file)
    If isNotMusic(fi.Extension.ToString) = True Then Continue For 'Checks file extension for non-music files; if test is true for-loop continues with next file
    trackCounter += 1 'Adds 1 to trackCounter
    Dim song As New musicInfo

    Dim tagFile As TagLib.File = TagLib.File.Create(fi.FullName)
    infoArtist = tagFile.Tag.Performers(0)

    With song
        .track = tagFile.Tag.Track
        .title = tagFile.Tag.Title
        .artist = tagFile.Tag.Performers(0)
        .album = tagFile.Tag.Album
        .extension = fi.Extension.ToString
    End With
    songs.Add(song)
Next
```

When I use this code on a folder filled with AC/DC songs, tagFile.Tag.Performers(0) returns "AC".

I looked up this problem elsewhere and from what I could see, only other tagging solutions such as MpTagThat and MP1 have [addressed this problem](http://forum.team-mediaportal.com/threads/multiple-music-genres-not-handled-correctly.103169/page-2) and made a patch.

I'm aware that the Performers tag is an array and the other half "DC" is likely stored in tagFile.Tag.Performers(1). However, I will eventually be separating each artist with a ";" in my code and if I left everything as is, AC/DC would be returned as "AC;DC".

Comment: In that code, the artist will only ever be "AC" since you arent passing the rest of the pieces to it. Any duets wont have the second artists. Since there cant be that many artists using a slash in the name, you could specifically look for 'AC' and fix that one.   If there are several, create a dictionary to convert/merge/expand the name when you see the first segment

Comment: ...before adding it to the collection, you could have an `AddArtist` method which you use while looping on the `Tag.Performers()` collection. Your class wouild need something like an `OtherArtists` collection for this, but it  would handle duets and seperate mentions `Featuring Bruce Springsteen`

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah, guess that'll have to do for now. It was easy enough to just make a function that looks for specific artists in a case statement and it combines the values. Wouldn't know what to do with a dictionary, haven't been there... yet.

Comment: @FluffySebbert Can't reproduce your problem. I get everything fine. And do *you* set the `AC/DC` as artist? if so, how? or is it already there (like, you bought it from ITunes.. etc.)?

Comment: @FluffySebbert I would suggest you open one of the files with [MP3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/). Also, it could be a problem with the TagType. I set the tags in Mp3Tag with ID3v2.3 and when I read it, `AC/DC` is read as a whole.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ the problem occurs with taglib-sharp, the tag artist was set as AC/DC. I probably manually set the tag a long time ago to all my AC/DC songs in Windows Explorer under "Contributing Artist". Not sure if it's possible to set the type with taglib-sharp to read files conditionally.